# Query multiple tables - return 1 match

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: A table of restaurants and a table of areas.  The "EntryID" key in the Addresses table is a number that is the same as the primary key of each record in the restaurant table.  So EntryID is a foreign key.  I want to be able to modify my PHP select script to search the database across these two tables.  Here is what I have right now:

```
  $RPrice = $_GET["price"]; 
  $RType = $_GET["type"];
  $RAtmosphere = $_GET["RAtmosphere"];
  $RArea = $_GET["RArea"];
if (!empty($RPrice)) $w[]="Foodlist.price='".mysql_real_escape_string($RPrice)."'";  
if (!empty($RType)) $w[]="Foodlist.ftype='".mysql_real_escape_string($RType)."'";
if (!empty($RAtmosphere)) $w[]="Foodlist.atmosphere='".mysql_real_escape_string($RAtmosphere)."'";
if (!empty($RArea)) $w[]="Addresses.area='".mysql_real_escape_string($RArea)."'";


if (count($w)) $where="WHERE ".implode(' AND ',$w); else $where=''; 
$sql="SELECT Foodlist.ID, Foodlist.name from Foodlist JOIN Addresses ON (Foodlist.ID = Addresses.EntryID) $where"; 


$result= mysql_query($sql);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $ID=$row['ID'];
  echo "<a class=\"cross-link\" href=\"javascript:ajaxpage('result.php?id=$ID', 'results2'); ajaxpage('videoloader.php?id=$ID', 'results1');\">".$row['name']."</a><div id=\"contentarea\"></div>";

  }
```

I've commented out the "area" portion out because that is something that will need to be changed.

I want to be able to maintain the same functionality as before, but I want to be able to search across multiple area records.  I hope this makes sense.  If you need more clarification, please let me know.

Foodlist(table) contains the following columns: ID, price, type, atmosphere
Addresses(table) contains the following columns: EntryID, area

Right now, the query is assuming that all of these columns (except entryID) are in foodList.  I need the query to search area from the Addresses table.  Also, I'm wanted to return 1 result from the query per ID.  It is possible that one record in the FoodList table will have multiple corresponding records in the Addresses table.  In this case, I only want it to return the one that matches the area given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT f.ID, name FROM Foodlist f JOIN Addresses a ON (f.ID = a.EntryID) $where
```

I believe this should be sufficient for what you need.

Comment: this doesn't work.  for example, say there is an ID in Foodlist '12'.  In the addresses tables, there might be a two records associated with '12' one with area = north and another with area = south.  I should only return one of these.  this query also only returns values that have a record in the addresses table.  it may be the case it doesn't.

Comment: Then in that case add LIMIT 1 and turn JOIN into LEFT JOIN and the problems will be solved.